# Transferring resources from Amazon S3 to Tomcat via Chef

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, chef-infra

I have a WAR file, ovmgmt.war.  My WAR is at amazon s3.I want to deploy that war using chef recipes.
Is it possible to do that ? Can someone please point me in right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots and lots of searching i found a very nice tutorial

> http://hipsterdevblog.com/blog/2014/06/22/retrieving-files-from-s3-using-chef-on-opsworks/

and the cookbook **"deployfile"** can be used from [github link](https://github.com/gitsubham/deployfile.git) :

> https://github.com/gitsubham/deployfile.git

Comment: The URLs you mentioned are not available

Answer (score 1):

The [s3_file](https://github.com/adamsb6/s3_file) cookbook offers a resource of the same name that can do this.